# Arrows crossing blocks TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I did several research and many tests and I didn't figure out how to draw the line from (U) and goes to the bottom of S and Q.
This is the code of what I did right now and I want your help to add the line wanted...

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{arm}{RGB}{100,140,171}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
 \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure} [htbp]
\hspace{-1.9cm}
\resizebox{!}{10cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto,>=stealth]

\tikzstyle{los} = [diamond, draw,fill=arm,text width=3em, text badly centered, text=white, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
 \tikzstyle{quadri} = [rectangle, draw, fill=arm, text width=6em, text centered,text=white , rounded corners, minimum height=2.5em]
 \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, color=black, -latex']


 \node[quadri] (A) {A};
 \node[quadri, below of=A, node distance=1.6cm] (B) {B};
 \node[quadri, below left=1cm and 2cm of B ] (C) {C};
 \node[los, below of=C , node distance=2.2cm] (D) {D};
 \node[quadri,below left=1cm and 1.6cm of D] (E) {E}; 
 \node[quadri,below of=E, node distance=1.6cm](F) {F};
 \node[quadri,below of=D, node distance=1.97cm](G) {G };
 \node[quadri,below of=G, node distance=1.6cm](H) {H};
 \node[quadri,below right=1cm and 1.6cm of D] (I) {I};
 \node[quadri,below of=I, node distance=1.6cm](J) {J};
  \node[quadri, below right=1cm and 2cm of B ] (K) {K};
\node[quadri,below left=1.3cm and 0.22cm of K] (L) {L};
\node[quadri,below of=L,node distance=1.6cm] (M) {M};
\node[los,below right of=K,node distance=3cm] (O) {O};
\node[quadri,below left=1cm and 0.05cm of O](P){P};
\node[quadri,below of=P, node distance=1.6cm](Q) {Q};
\node[quadri,below right=1cm and 0.05cm of O](R){R};
\node[quadri,below of=R, node distance=1.6cm](S) {S};
\node[quadri,right of=A ,node distance=3.5cm](T) {T};
\node[quadri, text width=7em,right of=T ,node distance=3.4cm](U){U};


\path [line] (A) -- (T);
\path [line] (T) -- (U);
\path [line] (A) -- (B);
\path [line] (B) -- (C);
 \path [line] (B) -- (K);
 \path [line] (C) -- (D);
 \draw[line] (D) -| node [near start,above] {$=0$} (E);
\path [line] (E) -- (F);
\draw[line] (D) -- node[right] {$=1$} (G);
\path [line] (G) -- (H);
\draw[line] (D) -| node [near start,above] {$=0$} (I);
 \path [line] (I) -- (J);
 \path [line] (K) -- (L);
 \path [line] (K) -- (O);
 \path [line] (L) -- (M);
 \draw[line] (O) -| node [near start,above] {$=1$} (P);
 \draw[line] (O) -| node [near start,above] {$>1$} (R);
 \path [line] (P) -- (Q);
 \path [line] (R) -- (S);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 }
  \caption{Flowchart}
  \label{fig:flowchart}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Hi luke. Do you mean an arrow starting on the right of `U` going to the right of `S` or pointing to both `S` and `Q`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It goes from right of (U) going right of the scheme and point (S) and (M) From the bottom!

Comment: Ok @AndrewSwann , i understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would like to recommend you to not use `\tikzstyle` to define your styles in favor of `\tikzset` (for further information see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)).

Another remark: I noticed you used both `\draw` and `\path`; actually, `\draw` is a shortcut for `\path[draw]` thus, as your style `line` already contains the key `draw`, there's not difference in using one or the other one. Notice: only in case both exploit the `line` style.

Also, the connections can be drawn much more easily thanks to a loop: indeed, most of the lines of code are identical.

Said that, the straight way to solve the problem is to use the library `calc`, which helps in defining a commodity coordinate useful to draw the paths.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{arm}{RGB}{100,140,171}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure} [htbp]
\hspace{-1.9cm}
\resizebox{!}{7.5cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto,>=stealth]

\tikzset{los/.style={diamond, draw,fill=arm,text width=3em, text badly centered, text=white, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{quadri/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=arm, text width=6em, text centered,text=white , rounded corners, minimum height=2.5em}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, color=black, -latex'}}


\node[quadri] (A) {A};
\node[quadri, below of=A, node distance=1.6cm] (B) {B};
\node[quadri, below left=1cm and 2cm of B ] (C) {C};
\node[los, below of=C , node distance=2.2cm] (D) {D};
\node[quadri,below left=1cm and 1.6cm of D] (E) {E}; 
\node[quadri,below of=E, node distance=1.6cm](F) {F};
\node[quadri,below of=D, node distance=1.97cm](G) {G };
\node[quadri,below of=G, node distance=1.6cm](H) {H};
\node[quadri,below right=1cm and 1.6cm of D] (I) {I};
\node[quadri,below of=I, node distance=1.6cm](J) {J};
\node[quadri, below right=1cm and 2cm of B ] (K) {K};
\node[quadri,below left=1.3cm and 0.22cm of K] (L) {L};
\node[quadri,below of=L,node distance=1.6cm] (M) {M};
\node[los,below right of=K,node distance=3cm] (O) {O};
\node[quadri,below left=1cm and 0.05cm of O](P){P};
\node[quadri,below of=P, node distance=1.6cm](Q) {Q};
\node[quadri,below right=1cm and 0.05cm of O](R){R};
\node[quadri,below of=R, node distance=1.6cm](S) {S};
\node[quadri,right of=A ,node distance=3.5cm](T) {T};
\node[quadri, text width=7em,right of=T ,node distance=3.4cm](U){U};


\foreach \source/\dest in {
A/T,T/U,A/B,B/C,B/K,C/D,E/F,G/H,I/J,K/L,K/O,
L/M,P/Q,R/S}{
\path [line]  (\source) -- (\dest);  
}
\path [line] (D) -| node [near start,above] {$=0$} (E);
\path [line] (D) -- node[right] {$=1$} (G);
\path [line] (D) -| node [near start,above] {$=0$} (I);
\path [line] (O) -| node [near start,above] {$=1$} (P);
\path [line] (O) -| node [near start,above] {$>1$} (R);


% useful coordinate: 
% it is defined as half way between S and Q shifted
% below of 1 cm
\coordinate (below scheme) at ($(S)!0.5!(Q)-(0,1)$);
% path from U to the south of the scheme
\path [line,-] (U.east) -- ($(U.east)+(1.5,0)$) |- (below scheme); % I used again the style line, but - removes the arrow that in this case should not be deployed
\path [line] (S|-below scheme)--(S);
\path [line] (below scheme)-|(M);

\end{tikzpicture}
 }
\caption{Flowchart}
\label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If your aim is to connect all the leaves of the tree, you might exploit a different solution:

```
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% THIS IS TO CONNECT U TO all
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\coordinate (below scheme) at ($(F)-(0,1)$);
\path [line,-] (U.east) -- ($(U.east)+(1.5,0)$) |- (below scheme); % I used again the style line, but - removes the arrow that in this case should not be deployed
\foreach \module in {F,H,J,M,Q,S}
\path [line] (\module|-below scheme)--(\module);
```

The snippet should replace:

```
% useful coordinate: 
% it is defined as half way between S and Q shifted
% below of 1 cm
\coordinate (below scheme) at ($(S)!0.5!(Q)-(0,1)$);
% path from U to the south of the scheme
\path [line,-] (U.east) -- ($(U.east)+(1.5,0)$) |- (below scheme); % I used again the style line, but - removes the arrow that in this case should not be deployed
\path [line] (S|-below scheme)--(S);
\path [line] (below scheme)-|(M);
```

in the previous document.

The new code defines the commodity coordinate (`below scheme`) to be 1cm south of `F`. Now, by exploiting the ability of the `calc` library to compute intersections, each arrow is defined as a path starting from `module |- below scheme` towards `module`. Please refer to the pgfmanual for further information on the `calc` library.

This provides you:

[image]

Comment: how can i add the same thing to F H J Q ?????

Comment: @luke: please see my edit answer. `:)`

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what i want. hope this will help others!